# Broken stick game

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory

Two players Alice and Bob play the following game consisting of $n-1$ turns. Initially the segment $[0,1]$ is given. Alice and Bob then alternate breaking one segment into two pieces. After all turns have passed, there are $n$ pieces. What is the maximum number of triangles Alice can guarantee forming?

If you cannot see the answer for the total can you at least give the answer for the case $n=4$ or higher because I'm lost.

Anything would help.

Thanks.

Comment: So what, Alice gets to keep all the pieces she herself broke off? If that is the case: Alice has $n/2$ pieces, and a triangle requires three pieces. So the answer would be the floor function of $n/6$. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: This is Problem 7 from MIT Primes/CROWDMATH 2017: The Broken Stick Problem. Since it's an online project like Polymath, I don't think you should post this on MSE.


  [1]: https://artofproblemsolving.com/polymath/mitprimes2017b/p

Comment: Are the resulting triangles to be disjoint?

Comment: Are the two pieces equal?

Comment: The segment [0,1] is given. 
Wouldn't there be the floor of $n/3$ triangles in total?